# How does FFmpeg concat videos and output same file prefix

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I have a lot of videos cut into three parts, and I want to concat them.
I now have the following bash to output videos in the folder to a file named mergedVideo.mp4.

```sh
for f in *.mp4 ; do echo file \'$f\' >> fileList.txt;done
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fileList.txt -c copy mergedVideo.mp4
```

All my input files are like `Something part1.mp4`, `Something part2.mp4`, `Something part3.mp4`
What I want is to output a file named `Something.mp4`

It is possible?
How can I modify my bash to achieve that~?

Comment: So you mean you also have files called `SomethingElse part1.mp4`, `SomethingElse part2.mp4` e.t.c in the same directory and you want the script to group them, based on common prefix,  and merge them?

Comment: Yes, but I don't mean to group them in the first place. If grouping them with the same prefix is also achievable, it would save me a lot of time moving videos with the same prefix to a folder.

Comment: Your bash script and the usage of `ffmpeg` are correct and should properly work. Why don't you try
it before asking? As a side note the `-c copy` option works
only if the all mp4 files are encoded with the same codecs. Otherwise the
merged stream will not be played back properly. In that case, remove
the `-c copy` option and specify the preferred codec type to allow re-encoding.

Comment: I'm familiar with bash. I can try, but I don't know how to extract the filename. I think it's something to do with RegExp? Any keywords is pleased to listen from. @tshiono

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I got your issue. If you want to extract the target filename out of the source filenames with regex, please try the posted script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat="^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*part[[:digit:]]+\.mp4$"
for f in *.mp4; do
    echo file \'$f\' >> fileList.txt
    [[ $f =~ $pat ]] && mergedvideo="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.mp4"
done
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fileList.txt -c copy "$mergedvideo"
```

Explanation of the regex `$pat`:

- `^([^[:space:]]+)` matches a non-space substring from the beginning of the
  string `$f` and is assigned to the shell variable `BASH_REMATCH[1]`.
  As for the provided example filenames, `BASH_REMATCH[1]` will be assigned to `Something`.
- `[[:space:]]*` matches a zero or more whitespace(s).
- `part[[:digit:]]+` matches a string "part" followed by digit(s).
- `\.mp4` matches the suffix.

**[Alternative]**

If you are familiar with `sed` as well, the following may be more readable and maintainable:

```
mergedvideo=$(sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*part[[:digit:]]+//' <<< "$f")
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a little bit to what I need.

I actually have spaces in my prefix name, and there's always a space before 'part' 

`pat="^(.*)[[:space:]]+part[[:digit:]]+\.mp4$"`

and it works.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I suppose your modification of the regex is reasonable and will work well even if the title contains a white space such as: `my movie part1.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

I extend [tshiono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8572380/tshiono)'s answer to be able to manipulate all the files in the same folders (just like [Marinos An](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555615/marinos-an) mentioned, the idea is to merge files with the same prefix)

Cases like a folder with the following files:

- Monday Blue part1.mp4
- Monday Blue part2.mp4
- Tuesday.mp4
- Wednesday part1.mp4
- Wednesday part2.mp4
- Wednesday part3.mp4

Expected Output:

- Monday Blue.mp4
- Tuesday.mp4
- Wednesday.mp4

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pat="^(.+)[[:space:]]+part[[:digit:]]+\.mp4$"
for f in *.mp4; do
    if [[ $f =~ $pat ]]; then
        echo file \'$f\' >> "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
    fi
done

for f in *.txt; do
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "${f%%.*}.txt" -c copy "${f%%.*}.mp4"
done
```